# Arrays en Pseint

Tags: pseint

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Pseint, pero cuando le doy seleccionar la opción" en efectivo me calcula mil pesos de más" y no funciona, mientras que cuando ejecuto el número 2 si funciona.
¿Cómo podría solucionar este este eror?
el programa consiste en lo siguiente:
Cuantos son los productos que ha pedido.-El importe total de la compra que ha hecho.-La forma de pago que ha solicitado.-Si el Pago fue al contado se deberá mostrar El descuento y si el pago fue al  crédito  se  deberá mostrar el  interés  del consumo además  de  indicar  las cuotas y el importe de cuota

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
    Definir i,cantidad,fila,pago,cuota Como entero;
    definir productos,continua Como Caracter;
    definir precio,total,descuento,des Como Real
    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Bienvenidos a la farmacia Universidad de Cundinarmarca 24/7";
    Dimension productos[250],cantidad[250],precio[250];
    Escribir " ";
    Escribir "INGRESAR ARTÍCULOS";
    Escribir " ";
    continua <- "si";
    i=1;
    
    Repetir
        Escribir "  ";
        Escribir Sin Saltar "Escriba el nombre del producto";leer productos[i];
        Escribir Sin Saltar "Precio Unitario :";Leer precio[i];
        Escribir Sin Saltar "Cantidad : "; leer cantidad[i];
        i<-i+1;
        Escribir sin saltar "¿Desea ingresar otro artículo (si/no)? ";Leer continua;
    Hasta Que continua ="no";
    Escribir " ";
    Escribir "Desea pagar en: "
    Escribir "1. En efectivo";
    escribir "2. Tarjeta";
    Leer pago;
    Escribir " ";
    Escribir "      ";escribir "COMPRA TOTAL ";
    Escribir "========================================================";
    Escribir "CANTIDAD      DESCRIPCIÓN     PRE. UNI.       PRE. TOTAL";
    Escribir " ";
    Para fila <-1 Hasta i-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        total<-cantidad(fila)*precio(fila);
        Escribir cantidad(fila),"             ",productos(fila),"  S/.    $",precio(fila),".         $",total;
        total<-total + cantidad(fila) * precio(fila);
    FinPara
    Escribir "========================================================";
    Escribir "                                                 $",total;
    Si pago=1 Entonces
        Escribir "Usted te ha pagado en efectivo";
        descuento=(total*0.2);
        Escribir "Su descuento fue del 20% que equivale a: ",descuento;
        Escribir "====================================================";
        total=total-descuento;
        Escribir "                        Su total es de: ",total;
    Fin Si
    Si pago=2 Entonces
        Escribir "                      Usted te ha pagado en tarjeta";
        Escribir "|Ingrese el número de cuotas en las que desea pagar|"
        Leer cuota;
        descuento=(total*0.3);
        Escribir " El 30% de interés es de: ", descuento;
        Escribir "El número de cuotas a pagar es de: ",cuota;
        des=descuento/cuota;
        Escribir "el valor de la cuota a pagar es de: ",des;
        Escribir "========================================";
        Escribir " Su total final es de: ",total+ descuento;
    Fin Si
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Creo que dentro de los if(si) pones para cambiar el valor de la variable: `=` en vez del operador de Pseint encargado de ello: `<-`.

Comment: ¿Me regala la entrada que ingresas y la salida que deseas?

Comment: Terminado de ingresar el pedido, el programa deberá solicitar que se ingrese la forma de pago. •Si  el  pago  es  al  contado,  se  le  hará  un  descuento  del  20%  del  total  de consumo.•Si el pago es al crédito (tarjeta) se le deberá cargar el 30% de interés y se pedirá     el     número     de     cuotas     en     las     que     desea     pagar.Finalmente el programa deberá mostrar en un solo mensaje: -Cuantos son los productos que ha pedido

Comment: .-El importe total de la compraque ha hecho.-La forma de pago que ha solicitado.-Si el Pago fue al contado se deberá mostrar El descuento y si el pago fue al  crédito  se  deberá mostrar el  interés  del consumo además  de  indicar  las cuotas y el importe de cuota.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes errores de sintaxis, al acceder a los valores de un arreglo debes utilizar los operadores de acceso `[]` y no `()`. Debe ser `arreglo[i]` y no `arreglo(i)`.

Obviando lo anterior, el error en tu lógica radica en el uso que le estas dando a tu acumulador `total`. Dicha variable debería guardar el total de todas las compras efectuadas, no obstante, tú lo reinicias al calcular el subtotal de un producto.

Basta modificar tu ciclo, y definir una variable temporal `subtotal` para que el resultado sea el esperado

```
 total<-0;
 Para fila <-1 Hasta i-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Definir subtotal como Real;
    subtotal<-cantidad[fila] * precio[fila];
    Escribir cantidad[fila],"             ",productos[fila],"  S/.    $",precio[fila],".         $",subtotal;
    total<-total + subtotal;  
FinPara
```

---

## El cargo extra al pagar con crédito

Más errores de sintaxis, la asignación debe ser con `<-` y no con `=`.

Obviando lo anterior, actualmente estas cálculando mal el número de cuotas, primero debes incrementar el total por 30%, y apartir de ahí calcular el número de cuotas a pagar.

```
    Si pago=2 Entonces
        Escribir "                      Usted te ha pagado en tarjeta";
        Escribir "|Ingrese el número de cuotas en las que desea pagar|"
        Leer cuota;
        Escribir " El 30% de interés es de: ", 0.3*total;
        Escribir "El número de cuoutas a pagar es de: ",cuota;
        total<-1.3*total;
        des<-total/cuota;
        Escribir "el valor de la cuota a pagar es de: ",des;
        Escribir "========================================";
        Escribir " Su total final es de: ",total;
    Fin Si
```

Answer (score 0):

En el caso en el que tengas psint en modo estricto al momento de asignar valor a una variable, es " <- " no, " = ".
Con el signo de " = " se comparan dos variables.